# Mongoid Relational Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, devise, mongoid

I am using rails3+mongoid+devise to create an application. I have users, and each user can have appontments, I am wondering if i should explicitly store a user_id in the appointment document or how to get mongoid to handle this automatically with the defined relationship.

The User and Appointment models are as follows

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  devise: database_authenticable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  field :username
  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :email, :case_sensitive => false
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  references_many :appointments
end

class Appointment
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :date, :type => Date, :default => Date.today
  referenced_in :user
end
```

I am wondering how to go about creating the appointment and having it associated with the current logged in user (current_user using devise).

Any advice on the following workout_controller, specifically line 2?

```
def create
  @appointment = current_user.Appointment.new(params[:appointment])
  if @appointment.save
    redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @appointment._id)
  else
    render('edit')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I believe your last line of the `Appointment` class should say `referenced_in :user` instead of `:person`.

Then, you should be able to fix line 2 of your controller as follows:

```
@appointment = current_user.appointments.new(params[:appointment])
```

After saving it, `current_user.appointments` should include the new appointment.

Comment: Oops, the :person instead of :user was a typo on my part. But, yes, it works now, brilliant. Forgot you need to use "appointments.new" instead of "appointment.new"